# implicit conversion of 'NSUInteger' to 'id'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am learning objective-c. I followed a book write the following code to test NSObject's key-value observer.

```
@implementation BNRObserver
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
   //ERROR: implicit conversion of 'NSUInteger' to 'id' is disallowed with ARC
    NSString *oldValue = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld];
    NSString *newValue = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew];
    NSLog(@"Observed: %@ of %@ was changed from %@ to %@",
          keyPath, object, oldValue, newValue);
}
@end
```

But  `objectForKeyI` complains:

```
implicit conversion of 'NSUInteger' to 'id' is disallowed with ARC
```

Why I get this error? how to fix it?

P.S. the above code is from the book : [Objective-C Programming The Big Nerd Ranch Guide 2nd Edition](http://www.bignerdranch.com/we-write/objective-c-programming.html).

Comment: The "keys" you're attempting to use are not NSObjects (but rather plain old integer enumeration values), while the keys of an NSDictionary must be NSObjects.  That is what the error message is telling you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong keys. The values that you are using are the observation options. You are after `NSKeyValueChangeOldKey` and `NSKeyValueChangeNewKey`.

i.e.:

```
NSString *oldValue = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeOldKey];
NSString *newValue = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a closer look at the error message you'll get that it can't convert from the type NSUInteger (a number) to id (any object). And if you look at the definition (hold the command-key down and click on NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld), you'll see the following:

```
NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld = 0x02
```

But a NSDictionary only allows objects for keys, not numbers.

=> Solution: take NSKeyValueChangeOldKey / NSKeyValueChangeNewKey as keys, which are of type NSString

```
NSString *oldValue = (NSString *)change[NSKeyValueChangeOldKey];
NSString *newValue = (NSString *)change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
```

And with modern obj-c you don't even have to use the objectForKey:-method

If you wish to see all content of the dictionary implement:

```
NSLog(@"%@", change);
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `@"old"` and `@"new"` but the defines constants `NSKeyValueChangeOldKey` and `NSKeyValueChangeNewKey`